# PhpStorm cannot load project after running npm install

Tags: laravel, npm, phpstorm

In my Laravel project I want to try use npm. After running `npm install` and restarting PhpStorm it stuck at loading project look like this:

[image: stuck in loading project]

And my Windows 10 CPU runs high. (the dialog can not be cancelled, I have to force close it)

I have tried this:

1. `Setting -> Editor -> File Types` -- added `node_modules` to "Ignore files and folders".
2. `Setting -> Directories` -- marked `node_modules` as Excluded Folder.

Both did not work!

I have stuck in this problem in a few days, hope somebody can take sometime to help me out!

```
PC: Windows 10 x64
PhpStorm 2017.1.2
node.exe: v7.6.0
```

Comment: You may try this: 1) close IDE; 2) go to PROJECT_FOLDER and delete `.idea` subfolder (contains this project settings); 3) launch IDE; 4) Use `Open` to point to the project root folder -- IDE will create new project from existing files. See if this will do any better this time.

Comment: thanks, it doesn't work to me. I try your method, and nothing happen. I try to uninstall phpstorm and install again, doesn't work too.

Comment: In such case: grab your `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in...) and submit it with the actual problem description to `Submit a Request` link on the top of the https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm page.

Comment: i try use yarn instead npm, phpstorm work well on my project !!! But yarn install will have one error : error An unexpected error occurred: `"EINVAL: invalid argument, symlink '../../../buble/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/var/www/laravel-vue-bulma-vue-admin/node_modules/acorn-object-spread/node_modules/.bin/acorn'".`  I try **yarn add acorn**, also the same error TT  @LazyOne @Mick

Answer (score 0):

It may be indexing the node_modules folder. You need to remove this from the project.

If you get it to open, you can do this in PHPStorm by right clicking the folder-> Mark Directory As -> Excluded.

You could delete the contents of the folder, then do this? You can just do an npm install again after.

Mick

Comment: I try this method, it doesn't work to me, maybe there some error on my pc. thanks to take your time.